# problem connecting to Apache Kafka from Java

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am trying to connect to one Kafka server.
in Java, I have configured:

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClient;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.NewTopic;
.
.
Properties properties = new Properties();
String bootstrapServers = "localhost:9092";
properties.put("bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServers);
properties.put("connections.max.idle.ms", 10000);
properties.put("request.timeout.ms", 5000);
try {
        AdminClient adminClient = AdminClient.create(properties);
        NewTopic newTopic = new NewTopic("testtopic", 1, (short)1); 
.
.
```

Although there is a configuration to use localhost, I get errors:

```
INFO: AdminClientConfig values: 
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
Jan 22, 2021 9:48:01 PM org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser$AppInfo <init>
INFO: Kafka version: 2.7.0
Jan 22, 2021 9:48:01 PM org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser$AppInfo <init>
INFO: Kafka commitId: 448719dc99a19793
Jan 22, 2021 9:48:01 PM org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser$AppInfo <init>
INFO: Kafka startTimeMs: 1611348481265
Jan 22, 2021 9:48:03 PM org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient initiateConnect
WARNING: [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Error connecting to node e4f0851caf23:9092 (id: 1001 rack: null)
java.net.UnknownHostException: No such host is known (e4f0851caf23)
```

Is there any additional configuration that I am missing?
This is only a sample code, I am trying to create one topic.

thank you!

Comment: Are you running the Kafka server in docker? Then you probably need to configure the `advertised.listeners` property of the Kafka server itself. This guide should help with details: https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you yuppie-flu!
I have to add:

KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=INTERNAL://kafka:9093,CLIENT://kafka:9092